# How can i use Loader to load data in a widget in android?

Tags: android

I want to use [Loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) update my data in widget,but i found it's difficult to use Loader in non-Activity/Fragment,and there is nothing about that in Reference or API Guide.Is anybody can tell me something about that?thx!

Answer (score 0):

A Loader is designed to be used from within a Fragment or an Activity since it is intended to be used to update some UI component when it finishes it's loading process.

If you need a custom implentation of the Loader, you can extend AsyncTaskLoader (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) and use it to process your results. Another option to initialize the LoaderManager for an activity from another class is to pass the instance of that Activity to the other class and the use this instance.